# Sql Date between issue

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I am writing stored procedure. I want to get list of table elements whose date is between every tuesday. I mean that for example if person exec procedure today's date is 2017-05-28 and I want to get List between 2017-05-23 00:00:00.000 and 2017-05-30 00:00:00.000. If todays date is 2017-05-28 again between  2017-05-23 00:00:00.000 and 2017-05-30 00:00:00.000. if date is 2017-05-01 between  2017-04-25 00:00:00.000 and 2017-05-02 00:00:00.000 
.
I wrote

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[mobile_group_match_list]    Script Date: 05/28/2017 00:03:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================

-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mobile_group_match_list]

    @refGroup bigint
AS
BEGIN

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    SELECT refLeaugeTeam INTO #TEAMS FROM [GROUP_TEAM] gt WHERE gt.refGroup=@refGroup

    SELECT Id,[Guid],HomeTeam,AwayTeam,HomePoint,EqualPoint,AwayPoint,MatchDate,HomeScore,AwayScore,@refGroup as refGroup
    FROM MATCH m
    WHERE ( (m.HomeTeam IN (SELECT refLeaugeTeam FROM #TEAMS)) OR (m.AwayTeam IN (SELECT refLeaugeTeam FROM #TEAMS)) )
    AND MatchDate>=DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()), 1)
    AND MatchDate<DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,GETDATE()) + 1, 1)

    SELECT lt.Id,T.Team FROM TEAM t,LEAUGE_TEAM lt WHERE lt.refTeam=t.Id
END
```

Date is not working it gives 2017-05-30 00:00:00.000 and 2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 but it has to be 2017-05-23 00:00:00.000 and 2017-05-30 00:00:00.000

How can I solve this problem ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
AND MatchDate>=dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate())/7 * 7 + 1,0)
    AND MatchDate<dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,-7,getdate())/7 * 7 + 1,0)
```